# pH-dependency of the acidic dissociation of carbonic acid

Tags: acid-base, ph

I know the product of $\ce{CO2 +H2O}$ yields $\ce{H2CO3}$. This is a reversible equation so $\ce{H2CO3}$ goes back to $\ce{H2O + CO2}$. However, my question is: Is there a certain pH which will dissociate $\ce{H2CO3}$ into $\ce{H+}$ and $\ce{CO3^2-}$ ions? If so, lets say you started with $2\ \mathrm{mol}$ of $\ce{H2O}$ and $1\ \mathrm{mol}$ of $\ce{CO2}$, how many moles of $\ce{H+}$ and $\ce{CO3^2-}$ ions will form?

Comment: Hi and welcome to chemistry.stackexchange.com. Since you already took the tour, all that remains is to guide you towards the [help] where you can find useful hints, e.g. on [how to format your posts with MathJax](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86) — check out what I did while editing your post ;)

Comment: Related: [Does H2CO3 exist in solution?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/39589/7951)

Comment: At what temperature and pressure? Solubility of CO2 depends on them strongly.

Comment: at 25 degrees and 1 atm